# How strong does the linear relationship has to be in order to use a linear regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

One of the Gauss-Markov assumptions is that the variables should have a linear relationship (so it produces unbiased estimates with the smallest variance). How strong does this relation have to be? Is there any rule of thumb?

The closest question I found was this one [How to check if i have strong linear relationship between dependent variable and independent variables in linear regression (OLS)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409431/how-to-check-if-i-have-strong-linear-relationship-between-dependent-variable-and), but it does not answer my question. So I'm sorry if my question is somehow repeated.

Comment: How would you measure the strength of linear relationship?

Comment: There aren't many rules that are useful. Sometimes the whole point of an exercise turns out to be showing that there is no (good) relationship between variables, contrary to someone's hope or hypothesis. In some fields $R^2$ that isn't virtually 1 is a sign of a botched experiment; in other fields $R^2$ that is virtually 1 is a sign of fraud (someone made up the data) or tautology (outcome and predictors are just versions of each other). It's a weak answer, but strong enough to impress people in your field is what it boils down to.

Comment: Complete lack of a linear relation does not violate any assumption, because it simply is a linear relation with zero slope.